# chave da mesma tabela

Tags: mysql

Fala galera beleza?

Estou fazendo um sistema de categoria infinita, então, na tabela tem o código e código da categoria pai. Eu queria relacionar esses dois campos pra quando eu apagar uma categoria o filho seja apagado tbm, assim não preciso tratar via código.

Mas como eu faço isso? Porque imagina que o código pai precisa ser cadastrado e se a categoria for o nível mais alto não vai ter pai, dando erro na chave.

Obrigado.

Comment: `Foreign Key no campo categoria_pai > e usar: ON DELETE CASCADE` ? Poderia colocar a estrutura da tabela juntamente com sua pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

Explicando a resposta do [@Rafael Withoeft](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/21222/rafael-withoeft):

Você deve ter uma chave estrangeira ( FK) em sua tabela **categoria_filho** que deve referenciar o **código da categoria pai** da tabela **categoria_pai** e também deve especificar que quando uma **categoria_pai** for excluída, a **categoria_fiho** deve ser excluída também. Isso é feito (em MySQL) da seguinte forma ( supondo que você já tenha criado previamente as tabelas):

```
ALTER TABLE 'nome_da_tabela_categoria_filho' 
ADD CONSTRAINT 'fk_categoria_pai' 
FOREIGN KEY ( 'cod_categoria_pai' ) 
REFERENCES 'nome_da_tabela_categoria_pai' ( 'nome_do_cod_categoria_pai' ) 
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Obrigado, acho que assim fica mais claro para ele mesmo..